# How to Select Rows Based on Column Values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I create a dataset like that,

```
Gender    response
female    yes
male      yes
female    yes
female    no
male      yes
female    no
male      yes
male      no
female    no
```

I like to count the yes responses and no responses genderwise. Like there are two females who said No and 2 females who said yes. There are three males said yes and one said no.

I tried to implement this using pandas dataframe.

So far I have tried to write down the query like

```
df.loc[df['Gender'] == 'female' & (df['response'] == 'yes')]
```

But I got error. How could I write it down?

Thank you.

Comment: The error you are getting is because you missed putting the first condition inside a bracket.  Anyways the line you are looking for is `df.groupby(['Gender', 'response'], as_index=False).size()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` with `groupby` method like this:

```
df.groupby('Gender')['response'].value_counts()
```

Response:

```
Gender  response
female  no          3
        yes         2
male    yes         3
        no          1
```

Answer (score 2):

Please cross tabulate

```
pd.crosstab(df['Gender'], df['response']).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group and count each category like this too:

```py
counts = df.groupby(['Gender','response']).size()

print(counts['female']['yes']) # Show the number of females who responded yes
```